# Parse xml Data from FormBuilder

Tags: android

I get the following response for FormBuilder. I want parse it.
How to parse it??

```
<LoactionApi><Status>OK</Status><ReportURL/><
Locations>
<Location><name>jack</name><number>357-151-04-00</number><Address>Ahmedabad</Address><City>Ahmedabad</City><State>Gujarat</State><ZIP>380007</ZIP><ZIP4>6518</ZIP4><UnitType/><UnitNumber/>
<MatchStatus>No Exact Match</MatchStatus>
<StatusCode>NM</StatusCode>
</LoactionApi>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you tried, like a xml parser, and what result you got... We are here to help you, but solutions to parse xml are easy to find on the internet, so please be more specific on what you have done to try to parse it, and the context you are trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check your XML response that you have shown over here. It is not at all valid !!!**

**For checking that your xml is valid. Validate it over here 
http://www.xmlvalidation.com/**

**Show me the correct xml. I will help you**